# Why am I not asked for application permission on an Apple Watch?

Tags: macos, apple-watch, administrator, sonoma

I want to be able to approve application requests from an Apple Watch (AW) by double-pressing the side button. The setting is titled `"Use AW to unlock your applications and your Mac"`. Despite having this setting enabled, I'm never prompted on my AW to permit the application whatever it requested. (Unlocking the Mac works though.)

[1] The setting is in `Settings > Touch ID & Password`, under section `Apple Watch` with a subtitle "Use AW to unlock your applications and your Mac". There, I have the particular AW's switch set to ON. And I've already tried setting it OFF and back ON.

- macOS 14.3 (23D56)
- watchOS 10.3.1 (21S651) [AW model A2684]

---

Related question: [Is it possible to disable macOS requesting permissions via Apple Watch, but still use it to unlock Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392243/is-it-possible-to-disable-macos-requesting-permissions-via-apple-watch-but-stil)

Comment: I would venture to guess that it’s a convenience factor.   Having the watch unlock things is designed to be efficient, but forcing it to confirm defeats that feature.  If you want confirmation, turn off that function

Comment: @Allan, thanks for the response. I thought confirmation on AW was meant as an _alternative_ means for all those "Touch ID or enter your password to allow this." prompts that one receives from various applications. At least that's my understanding of the "Use AW to unlock your applications and your Mac" subtitle, mentioned in my question. The second part works ("... your Mac") but not the first part ("... your applications ...").

The convenience factor for me would be _not_ having to reach over to the Touch ID button, as the laptop is relatively distant (compared to AW).

Comment: The watch is acting like a Proxcard where you hold it close to a reader. Since you have the card in your possession, the system knows it’s you.   Same with the watch.  When you put it on, you had to enter your passcode (PIN).  Subsequently, you can open your computer/app without needing to authenticate.

Comment: @Allan yes. But one still has to authenticate, via Touch ID or entering the password, for some superadmin actions. F.e. when 1Password asks for Touch ID authorization. It's for these actions that I'd like to be able to (also) use AW for (besides Touch ID). Or have misunderstood the subtitle "Use AW to unlock your applications"?

Comment: You’ve got a different question there. The original title reads as if you see the watch not doing something as it should while the second is a request for a feature

Comment: @Allan, bear with me please, but doesn't the name of the setting (`"Use AW to unlock your applications and your Mac"`) containing an `"and"` conjunction imply that there are 2 aspects to this feature. For me, `"your Mac"` works, but `"your applications"` doesn't. I think the same follows from the title of the related question I linked to ("Is it possible to disable macOS requesting permissions via Apple Watch, but still use it to unlock Mac?"), no?